# Drupal 7 - htaccess redirect if URL contains a certain string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal

How would I write a redirect rule in my htaccess file if the URL contains a certain string?

Example:

https://www.mywebsite.com/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=2977d8d74f63d7f8fedbea018b7a1d05&ns=2&cb=1143295674

https://www.mywebsite.com/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=2977d8d74f63d7f8fedbea018b7a1d05&ns=3&cb=1461264764

https://www.mywebsite.com/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=2977d8d74f63d7f8fedbea018b7a1d05&ns=1&cb=1693249588

If it contains **_Incapsula_Resource** then redirect to https://www.mywebsite.com

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
Instead of **_Incapsula_Resource**, use **SWJIYLWA=**

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} SWJIYLWA=

RewriteRule .* /? [R,L]